# PHP Getting all unique board results for poker

Tags: php, algorithm, for-loop, poker

I am currently trying to make a poker algorithm that determines the chance of winning a hand. It needs to be extremely fast because it will have to loop through hundreds of thousands of different hands each time.

What I'm struggling to do is to be able to get all the unique hands that could possible come up in a board. A board contains 5 cards.

Each time a card comes up on the board, that card cannot come up again.

So what I've been doing to get all the possible board combinations is loop through all possible results using for loops.

For this example, I'm going to get only the first 3 cards of the board.

The code is something like this:

```
// $card_set_count is the amount of cards left in the deck after taking away the
// user's hand cards.
for($i=0;$i<$card_set_count;$i++) {
    // First known card
    $known_card1 = $card_set[$i];

    for($j=0;$j<$card_set_count;$j++) {
        // Second known card
        $known_card2 = $card_set[$j];
        // Skip the card if we already have it out
        if($known_card1 == $known_card2) continue;

        for($k=0;$k<$card_set_count;$k++) {
            // Third Known Card
            $known_card3 = $card_set[$k];
            // Skip card if the card is already out
            if($known_card3 == $known_card2 || $known_card1 == $known_card3) continue

            // Create board
            $board = array();
            $board[] = $known_card1;
            $board[] = $known_card2;
            $board[] = $known_card3;
        }
    }
}
```

This does get me all possible board combinations. The only problem is it gets me duplicate values too, for example the boards:

Ad 6d 4c

is the same as

4c Ad 6d

I could run array_unique() on my list of boards, but the problem comes here with my forloop having to loop through 91020 hands. This is super slow for my algorithm.

I was just wondering if someone had a better idea of looping through the possible boards.

Storing the board values in an array and then testing to see if the card value is in the list is still very slow. Is there a way of looping only through unique board combinations?

Comment: After re-reading more attentively, I realised I'd misinterpreted your question, so I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is basically ok, but instead of iterating from 0 to `$card_set_count` each time, the second card should only be picked from the cards that come after the first card, and the third card should only be picked from the cards that come after the second card, like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<$card_set_count - 2;$i++) {
    for($j=$i + 1;$j<$card_set_count - 1;$j++) {
        for($k=$j + 1;$k<$card_set_count;$k++) {
            $board = array();
            $board[] = $card_set[$i];
            $board[] = $card_set[$j];
            $board[] = $card_set[$k];
            // evaluate hand ...
        }
    }
}
```

With 50 cards left in the pack, that gives 19600 combinations. You could prune these combinations further, because for some hands the suit isn't important, but this may get very complicated.

---

*At first I misread your question, and gave the answer below, which doesn't fully address your specific problem. I haven't deleted it because it already had an upvote, so someone apparently found it useful.*

Create an array with all the cards. Create a variable with the number of cards still left: `cardsLeft = 52`. Then, when you need to pick a card, choose at random from card 1 to 52, swap the chosen card with card 52, and set `cardsLeft` to 51. Next card, you choose from card 1 to 51, swap it with card 51, set `cardsLeft` to 50, and so on...
Whenever you need to start a new game with a new deck, just reset cardsLeft to 52. No need to re-initialize or shuffle the array.

I haven't used php in years, but here's an example in Javascript; it's quite self-explanatory. Run the code snippet to draw a poker hand for three players (see output in console).

```js
function Deck() {
    this.cards = [];
    this.left = 52;
    for (var suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++) {
        for (var number = 0; number < 13; number++) {
            this.cards.push("23456789TJQKA".charAt(number) + "cdhs".charAt(suit));
        }
    }
}
Deck.prototype.draw = function() {
    if (this.left == 0) this.shuffle();
    var pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.left);
    var swap = this.cards[pick];
    this.cards[pick] = this.cards[--this.left];
    this.cards[this.left] = swap;
    return swap;
}
Deck.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    this.left = 52;
}

var d = new Deck();
document.write("player 1: " + d.draw() + "," + d.draw() + "<BR>");
document.write("player 2: " + d.draw() + "," + d.draw() + "<BR>");
document.write("player 3: " + d.draw() + "," + d.draw() + "<BR>");
document.write("flop: " + d.draw() + "," + d.draw()+ "," + d.draw() + "<BR>");
document.write("turn: " + d.draw() + "<BR>");
document.write("river: " + d.draw());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The for loop in the first part really solved my issue- I just couldn't visualise the data in my head properly but after seeing that code it works out great now.

Answer (score 0):

create an array with all cards to pull cards from

create an empty array for cards already used

when getting a card from the array with all cards add it to the second array and remove it from the fist array (unset) so you can't pick it again...

```
$chosen_card = array_rand($card_set);      // just choosing a card randomly to simulate whatever way you currently pick one 
$known_cards[] = $card_set[$chosen_card];  // copy the card to the know_cards array
unset($card_set[$chosen_card]);            // remove cards from unused cards
```

This way $chosen_card has only unused cards at any time and $known_cards has all alredy taken cards.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want all unique combinations from a known set, you could implement the following algorithm:

```php
$card_set = [1,2,3,4,5];
$k = 3;
$n = count($card_set);
$combs = [];
$stack = [[[],0,0]];

while (!empty($stack)){
  $params = array_pop($stack);

  $current_hand = $params[0];
  $i = $params[1];
  $len = $params[2];

  if ($len == $k){
    array_push($combs,$current_hand);
  } else {
    if ($i < $n - 1){
      array_push($stack,[$current_hand,$i + 1,$len]);
    }
    if ($i < $n){
      array_push($current_hand,$card_set[$i]);
      array_push($stack,[$current_hand,$i + 1,$len + 1]);
    }
  }
}

print_r($combs);
```